# How to change the position of an element to left when a radio button is checked?

Tags: javascript, radio-button

I want to change the position of an element to left when a radio button is checked.But this code is not working.

```
if(document.getElementById("red").checked){
document.querySelector(".sliding-content").style.left = "-100%";
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using JQuery, this allows you to move an element based on a click on a radio button.

```js
$("#redRadio").click(function() {
  $('#test').css('margin-left', '100px');
});
```

```css
#test {
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form action="">
  <input id="redRadio" type="radio" name="color" value="red">Red<br>
</form>

<div id="test"></div>
```

By request, pure JS:

```js
function moveRed() {
  document.getElementById("test").style.marginLeft = "100px";
}
```

```css
#test {
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<form action="">
  <input onclick="moveRed()" id="redRadio" type="radio" name="color" value="red">Red<br>
</form>

<div id="test"></div>
```

Comment: Thanks,it works.But I want to do it using JavaScript.

Comment: I'll add a pure JS version.

Comment: Updated with pure JS